# How to convert SearchQuerySet into QuerySet without changing order?

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I have `doctors` object of `SearchQuerySet` type and i want to convert into QuerySet:

**doctors** = SearchQuerySet().dwithin('location', point_data, max_dist).distance('location',point_data).order_by('distance')

```
results = [ r.pk for r in doctors ]

address_key = Address.objects.all()

add_obj = address_key.filter(pk__in=results)
```

Now **add_obj** is type of QuerySet.

`add_obj` queryset does not have same order like `doctors` SearchQuerySet has order of pk.

Comment: please add more context to your question, wihch is unclear. What is `address_key`, for example?

Comment: address_key = Address.objects.all()

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to use the order of the list when using `pk__in`.

An alternative is to use [`in_bulk`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk) to fetch all of the objects, keyed by id. Then construct an ordered list using a list comprehension.

```
results = [r.pk for r in search_results]
objects = MyModel.objects.in_bulk(results)
objects_in_order = [obj[pk] for pk in objects]
```

Comment: It is right but i am not clear at line 2 and 3 .please help me

Comment: The third line should be `[obj[pk] for pk in objects]`, where `objects` is the variable from line 2.

Comment: thanks but objects_in_order is a list but i want to QuerySet type.

Comment: You can create a queryset without the required ordering,  or a list in the required order . As far as I know it isn't possible to create a queryset in the required order.